# List all WooCommerce product attribute names

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

Does Woocommerce have a short way of listing the attribute names outside of the main Woocomerce templates ie: single-product or product-archive?

This code almost gives me the desired result it will output my 4 attribute titles but repeats the attribute name for each product. all I need is output a list of my attribute names.

```
$query_args = array(
        'status'    => 'publish',
        'limit'     => -1,
    );
    foreach( wc_get_products($query_args) as $product ){
        foreach( $product->get_attributes() as $taxonomy => $attribute ){
            $attribute_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
            foreach ( $attribute->get_terms() as $term ){
               echo '<li class="pa-filter-item"><a href="">' . $attribute_name . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
```

The aim is to output a list of attribute names that will be used to create filter to allow the terms to be filtered inside a custom template page and not a Woocommerce page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using custom attributes that can be set on a single product, you can get all your product attribute taxonomy objects using [wc_get_attribute_taxonomies()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/wc-attribute-functions.php#L44-L85) function like:

```
foreach ( wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() as $attribute ) {
    echo '<li class="pa-filter-item"><a href="">' . $attribute->attribute_label . '</a></li>';
}
```

Or you can use a custom [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) query:

```
global $wpdb;

$attribute_labels = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT attribute_label FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies WHERE attribute_name != '' ORDER BY attribute_name ASC;" );

foreach ( $attribute_labels as $attribute_label ) {
    echo '<li class="pa-filter-item"><a href="">' . $attribute_label . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Literally the one man i was hoping that would answer this question thanks man